# How to execute a Python script when an event is triggered in nginx-rtmp-module?

Tags: python, bash, nginx, rtmp, nginx-rtmp

I have already implemented a live streaming and transcoding platform using nginx-rtmp. I want to collect some metrics during the transcoding process, such as video quality, bitrate, start time, and duration of the live stream.

I have written these functionalities in a Python file and I want nginx-rtmp to execute this code when specific events（exec_publish and so on...） are triggered. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.